# Calculate mean of all values below the diagnonal line in an adjacency matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, mean

I have an adjacency matrix **M**, something like this:

```
[1  2   0   2   4
 2  1   2   0  -1
 0  3   1   2   3
 2  0   2   1   0
 4 -1   3   0   1]
```

I want to calculate the mean of all values below (but not including) the diagonal. The final output should be **1.5**.

To get those values, I thought I'd use `N = tril(M,-1)`. The issue is that I now have zeros in upper and lower part of the matrix **N** and therefore `mean(sum(N)./sum(N~=0))` wouldn't work. Since I also have negative values, I can't just do the mean of values >=0 either. How can I do this?

Comment: How do you get `1.2928`? Shouldn't it be `1.5`?

Comment: My bad, I input the wrong data. Question corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In one line using [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) to extract just the values below the diagonal:

```
M = [ 1  2  0  2  4;
      2  1  2  0 -1;
      0  3  1  2  3;
      2  0  2  1  0;
      4 -1  3  0  1];

mean(M(tril(true(size(M)),-1)))
```

This returns `1.5` as @excaza indicated.

Comment: Nice, very clever! Would you mind expanding it so folks can understand what's happening?